# JRuby - Calling Java class - Cannot import class 'com.foo.bar' as 'bar'

Tags: jruby, logstash

I am getting the below error when in import a custom jar.

```
require 'java'
require '/path/custom.jar'
java_import 'com.foo.bar'
```

The error reported is:
  cannot import class `com.foo.bar' as`bar'

I am trying to built a custom logstash input plugin.

Answer (score 0):

as it says because `java_import 'com.foo.bar'` is likely not a class-name, so you need to specify a (qualified) class-name or you can import the whole package with a `java_package` declartion

if `'com.foo.bar'` is a "valid" Java class-name (which is quite bad practice) it simply won't work since in Ruby constant names start with upper-case, you will be left with doing the import into the current name space (module) on your own e.g. : `Bar = Java::com.foo.bar`

Comment: it was a classname. I created another class called TestClass and that worked. No idea why the other class didnt work.